# YouTube API: Can I get a list of videos from a stream ordered by priority, or with a flag saying if they're highlighted or not?

Tags: php, xml, youtube, youtube-api

Currently I'm pulling through a number of videos from the following YouTube channel: www.youtube.com/user/UCASonline

As you can see, on that channel some of the videos (at the top) are highlighted pink. Those videos are the ones that I want to come first on the micro-site I'm building for them, with all other videos following below in the list.

Is it possible to distinguish whether a video is highlighted or not? Or can I get them in an ordered list, highest priority first?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as far as i know there is no option in zend gdata youtube api to identify which video is highlighted

Comment: Hmph. Annoying. Thanks for letting me know :)